# Haskell Pattern Matching on the Empty Set

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I'm changing some Haskell code from using lists to sets. I understand everything required, I think, but I'm not sure how to pattern match on sets. Lists have this nice literal syntax that seems hard to emulate with the Set constructor. For example, I might have some code like this:

```
foo [] = []
foo x = other_thing
```

How can I write this code so it uses Sets instead of lists?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well, you can't.

`Set` is an *abstract data type*<sup>[0]</sup> that deliberately hides its internal representation, primarily to maintain invariants of the data structure that can't be statically-enforced by the type system (specifically, the standard library `Data.Set.Set` is a binary search tree).

Losing the ability to pattern match on an abstract data type is an unpleasant bit of collateral damage, but oh well. Your options are roughly:

- Use boolean predicates and guards, e.g. `null`, as in trinithis's answer.
- Convert the `Set` to a list. Most of the time this is silly but if you want to iterate through the set anyway, it works well enough.
- Enable [GHC's `ViewPatterns` extension](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#view-patterns), which provides syntactic sugar for using accessor functions where a pattern match would normally go.
- Avoid making these sort of checks in the first place--if you have a `Set`, treat it like a *set*, and work with it as a whole for mapping, filtering, etc. Not always possible, but can lead to cleaner code with fewer explicit conditionals/iterations.

View patterns would let you write something that looks like this:

```
foo (setView -> EmptySet) = []
foo (setView -> NonEmpty set) = other_thing
```

...where `setView` is a function you write. Not really much of a gain here, but can be nice for more complex pseudo-patterns

For avoiding explicit checks, besides well-known set operations such as `union` and `intersection`, consider making use of the `filter`, `partition`, `map`, and `fold` functions in `Data.Set`.

**[0]:** See [this paper](http://userweb.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf) (warning: PDF) for the definition of the term as I'm using it.

Answer (score 36):

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

foo set
  | Set.null set = bar
  | otherwise = baz
```

Comment: @simonjpascoe: Wait, we can give *simple* answers? And here all this time I thought there was a three-paragraph minimum...