# Polymorphic class-constrained instances

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, instances

I want to make all types that are instances of `Enum` and `Bounded` also an instances of `Random`. The following code does this and should work (with the appropriate extensions enabled):

```
import System.Random

instance (Enum r, Bounded r) => Random r where
   randomR (hi, lo) = inFst toEnum . randomR (fromEnum hi, fromEnum lo)
      where inFst f (x,y) = (f x, y)
   random = randomR (maxBound, minBound)
```

But I am aware this is bad style because `instance (Enum r, Bounded r) => Random r` creates an instance for all `r`, just with type checks for `Enum` and `Bounded` rather than just putting an instance on types that are `Enum` and `Bounded`. This effectively means I'm defining an instance for all types `:(`.

The alternate is that I have to write standalone functions that give me the behavior I want and write some boilerplate for each type I want to be an instance of `Random`:

```
randomBoundedEnum :: (Enum r, Bounded r, RandomGen g) => g -> (r, g)
randomBoundedEnum = randomRBoundedEnum (minBound, maxBound)

randomBoundedEnumR :: (Enum r, Bounded r, RandomGen g) => (r, r) -> g -> (r, g)
randomBoundedEnumR (hi, lo) = inFst toEnum . randomR (fromEnum hi, fromEnum lo)
   where inFst f (x,y) = (f x, y)

data Side = Top | Right | Bottom | Left 
   deriving (Enum, Bounded)

-- Boilerplatey :( 
instance Random Side where
   randomR = randomBoundedEnumR
   random = randomBoundedEnum

data Hygiene = Spotless | Normal | Scruffy | Grubby | Flithy
   deriving (Enum, Bounded)

-- Boilerplatey, duplication :(
instance Random Hyigene where
   randomR = randomBoundedEnumR
   random = randomBoundedEnum
```

Are there any better alternatives? How should I manage this problem? Should I not even be attempt this at all? Am I overly worried about boilerplate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as I just answered to a [slightly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944756/can-haskell-guard-on-abstract-data-types-in-a-polymorphic-function/3945125#3945125), you can use a newtype wrapper - this is the common and safe way to make such instances without annoying the entire community.

```
newtype RandomForBoundedEnum a = RfBE { unRfBE :: a}
instance (Enum a, Bounded a) => Random (RandomForBoundedEnum a) where
    ....
```

In this manner, users who want to use this instance simply need to wrap (or unwrap) the calls:

```
first unRfBE . random $ g :: (Side, StdGen)
```